# Removing images in header with OpenXML SDK

Tags: c#, openxml, openxml-sdk

I have worked a bit with OpenXML SDK, and made a POC of replacing images in a header in a word document. However, when I try to call DeletePart or DeleteParts with the images I want to remove, it doesn't go as expected.

When I open the word doc afterwards, where there before was an image, there now is a frame with the text "This image cannot currently be displayed" and a red cross.

From a bit of googling it appears as if the references have not been completely removed, but I can't find any help on how to do that..

Below is an example of how I delete images. I only add some of them to the list, because I need to remove all but the ones with a specific uri..

```
//...

foreach(HeaderPart headerPart in document.MainDocumentPart.HeaderParts) {

    List<ImagePart> list = new List<ImagePart>();
    List<ImagePart> imgParts = new List<ImagePart> (headerPart.ImageParts);

    foreach(ImagePart headerImagePart in imgParts) {

         string newUri = headerImagePart.Uri.ToString();
              if(newUri != uri) {
                   list.Add(headerImagePart);
              }
         }

    headerPart.DeleteParts(list);
}
//...
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Images are made up of 2 parts in OpenXml; you have the actual image itself and you also have details of the `Picture` container that the image is displayed within in the document.

This makes sense if you think about an image being displayed more than once in the same document; details of the image can be stored once and the position(s) of the image can be stored as many times as needed.

The following code will find any `Drawing` objects that contain the `ImagePart` objects that you wish to delete. This is done by matching the `Embed` property of the `Blip` against the Id of the `ImagePart`.

```
using (WordprocessingDocument document = WordprocessingDocument.Open(filename, true))
{
    foreach (HeaderPart headerPart in document.MainDocumentPart.HeaderParts)
    {
        List<ImagePart> list = new List<ImagePart>();
        List<ImagePart> imgParts = new List<ImagePart>(headerPart.ImageParts);
        List<Drawing> drwdDeleteParts = new List<Drawing>();
        List<Drawing> drwParts = new List<Drawing>(headerPart.RootElement.Descendants<Drawing>());

        foreach (ImagePart headerImagePart in imgParts)
        {
            string newUri = headerImagePart.Uri.ToString();
            if (newUri != uri)
            {
                list.Add(headerImagePart);

                //you also need to find the Drawings the image was related to
                IEnumerable<Drawing> drawings = drwParts.Where(d => d.Descendants<Pic.Picture>().Any(p => p.BlipFill.Blip.Embed == headerPart.GetIdOfPart(headerImagePart)));

                foreach (var drawing in drawings)
                {
                    if (drawing != null && !drwdDeleteParts.Contains(drawing))
                        drwdDeleteParts.Add(drawing);
                }
            }
        }

        foreach (var d in drwdDeleteParts)
        {
            d.Remove();
        }

        headerPart.DeleteParts(list);
    }
}
```

As you pointed out in the comments, you'll need to add a using statement:

```
Pic = DocumentFormat.OpenXml.Drawing.Pictures;
```

Comment: Thank you very much! This gave me a much better understanding of the issue at hand, and resolved my issue completely! 

I did have a little problem running the code, but adding using Pic = DocumentFormat.OpenXml.Drawing.Pictures; solved that :) Once again, thank you very much!!

Comment: Good point @anl_extrico, I've edited the answer to include that for any future readers. You're welcome by the way, I'm glad I could help.